# Django - invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, django

I know about this exception but I don't know about how is this error is showing. I get `Integer` number from the request and I printed the type of number it says **type of Int** so how?

here is my code:

```
product = Product.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['prod_id'])

general = GeneralInfo(name=post.get('general-name'), product=product)

general.save()
```

and I tried

```
product = Product.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['prod_id'])

general = GeneralInfo(name=post.get('general-name'), product_id=int(product.id))

general.save()
```

and still getting error. What's the problem here?

Comment: can you check  your product instance ??

Comment: Could you also add your Product model here

Comment: @Robert, I checked

Comment: @anurag do you mean that do i imported product model?

Comment: post the code of the `Product` and `GeneralInfo` model and the full error stacktrace.

Comment: No, no. Can you add your `product` model in the question, which would help figuring out the issue. also if you are calling `product = Product.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['prod_id'])` in a view, you could get prod_id directly. refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404